# firejail with "--profile"-option

Tags: security

has anyone any idea how I can get the "--profile"-option to work with firejail?

I want to start tor-browser within the sandbox.
 My normal command would be: "./start-tor-browser.desktop" from within the respective folder.
 When typing "firejail ./start-tor-browser.desktop" everything works fine. Tor-browser gets started within firejail with the default profile.

Yet it should be possible to reuse an existing profile for this application (as described here: https://l3net.wordpress.com/2014/09/19/firejail-a-security-sandbox-for-mozilla-firefox/).
 So "firejail –profile=/etc/firejail/firefox.profile ./start-tor-browser.desktop" is supposed to work.
 Tor-browser should be started with the firefox profile. But that´s exactly what doesn´t work in my case.
 My terminal keeps giving me the info: "/bin/bash: ./start-tor-browser.desktop: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden", i.e. "file or folder not found".

I really dont´t know why that is.
 Can anybody help me?
 Tnx in advance.
 Rosika

P.S.: 
 system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, 64bit